# Welche Präposition gehört zum Substantiv "Aggression"?

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Die Aggression seinem Bruder gegenüber fällt über sich her.

```
The aggression towards his brother is eating him alive.
```

Kann man auch diese Redewendung verwenden: Jdn. in der Luft zerreißen?

Comment: Die Übersetzung von `eating somebody alive` ist nicht `über sich herfallen` und auch nicht `über jemanden herfallen`. Besser wäre `jemanden/etwas (bei lebendigem Leib) verzehren`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Aggression jemandem gegenüber" is correct. Possible also "Seine Aggressionen gegenüber seiner Frau" oder "gegen seine Frau".
But your sentence is wrong: 
Die Aggression seinem Bruder gegenüber fällt über sich her.

You can say: Er fällt über ihn her – but not: Er fällt über sich (selber) her.
And you can't say: Die Aggression fällt über sich her. That makes no sense.

Comment: Interestingly this answer was accepted, although you didn't explain what would be the correct way. What, for instance, would be your suggestion to phrase the German sentence instead?

Comment: *Die Aggression gegenüber seinem Brüder frisst ihn auf/frisst in bei lebendigem Leib* or *... fällt über ihn her*, but **never** *fällt über sich her*.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the poster wanted to say. But I assume that the agressive brother feels quilty because of his agressive behaviour.

Comment: Below someone suggested: Seine Aggressionen machten ihm zu schaffen. That would be quite acceptable. Or: Er litt sehr unter diesen Aggressionen. Or: Er haßte sich wegen diesen Aggressionen.

Comment: @rogermue I don't quite know what your comment is to say, but still my comment is valid - you never say *Die Agreesion gegenüber seinem Bruder fällt über sich her*. That would mean the agression is eating the aggression alive.

Comment: I don't understand your post: I said: " Die Agression gegenüber seinem Bruder fällt über sich her" - that is no reasonable German. Or do you see it differently?

Answer (score 8):

> Die Aggression seinem Bruder gegenüber

ist OK.

Etwas einfacher ist

> Die Aggression gegen seinen Bruder

Für `is eating him alive` passt `fällt über ihn her` aber nicht (btw: Es muss "über ihn" heißen, nicht "über sich"). Besser vielleicht

> Die Aggression gegen seinen Bruder macht ihn wahnsinnig.
>
> Die Aggression gegen seinen Bruder belastet ihn schwer.

Oder der Vorschlag von christian.s, der näher am Englischen ist:

> Die Aggression gegen seinen Bruder zehrt ihn auf.

---

`Jemanden in der Luft zerreißen` heißt `stark mit jemandem schimpfen`, das passt hier nicht.

Comment: Gibt es einen Grund für den Downvote? Was kann ich besser machen?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add another translation:

> Die Aggression seinem Bruder gegenüber **macht ihm zu schaffen**.